# Correct Ant/Ivy configuration for downloading both jars and sources along

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I want to resolve both jar and source dependencies using Ant/Ivy. The reason is that I want to provide my developers with help in accessing source code and related inline documentation. Not all libraries that our project use are public, so my goal is to provide sources to our own company-private dependencies than source decompiling from the IDE (IntelliJ searches only on Maven for sources!!)

Currently I use the following:

```
<property name="project.ivy.settingsFile" value="${basedir}/.ant/conf/ivy-settings.xml"/>
<property name="ivy.artifactPattern" value="[artifact]-[revision]-[type].[ext]"/>
<target name="ivy-retrieve">
    <property name="version" value="dev"/>
    <ivy:configure override="true" file="${project.ivy.settingsFile}"/>

    <ivy:resolve file="phoenix-ivy.xml" conf="provided,compile,runtime,test,junit" />
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" conf="*" type="jar,bundle" pattern="${project.webapp.lib}/${ivy.artifactPattern}" file="phoenix-ivy.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" conf="compile,compileOnly,auth-iccrea,auth-mps,auth-db" type="jar,bundle,source,javadoc"
                  pattern="build/lib-compile/${ivy.artifactPattern}" file="phoenix-ivy.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" conf="testCompile" type="jar,bundle" pattern="build/lib-testcompile/${ivy.artifactPattern}" file="phoenix-ivy.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" conf="testRuntime" type="jar,bundle" pattern="build/lib-testruntime/${ivy.artifactPattern}" file="phoenix-ivy.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" conf="runtime" type="jar" pattern="build/lib-runtime/${ivy.artifactPattern}" file="phoenix-ivy.xml"/>

</target>
```

Using the above `artifactPattern` I end up with two problems

## Problem 1: the "-jar" suffix

[image]

```
build/lib-compile/activation-1.1.1-jar.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-bpmn-converter-6.0.0-jar.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-bpmn-converter-6.0.0-javadoc.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-bpmn-converter-6.0.0-source.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-bpmn-model-6.0.0-jar.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-bpmn-model-6.0.0-javadoc.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-bpmn-model-6.0.0-source.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-dmn-api-6.0.0-jar.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-dmn-api-6.0.0-javadoc.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-dmn-api-6.0.0-source.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-dmn-model-6.0.0-jar.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-dmn-model-6.0.0-javadoc.jar
build/lib-compile/activiti-dmn-model-6.0.0-source.jar
```

I don't like this, because IntelliJ doesn't match the jar with the sources and doesn't help me a lot with source decompilation.

Probably what I want is to omit the "-jar" suffix from the main artifact and leave "-javadoc" and "-source"

When in IntelliJ I try to download source for any artifact I get an error that sources are not found

[image: Source not found]

```
Sources for 'cxf-rt-features-metrics-3.3.5-bundle.jar' not found
```

## Problem 2: confusion with the bundles

[image: Bundles]

```
build/lib-compile/jackson-core-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-databind-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-dataformat-properties-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-datatype-guava-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-datatype-joda-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.2-bundle.jar
build/lib-compile/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.11.2-bundle.jar
```

Some artifacts are available only as `bundle` type ([example here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.2), but [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.2/) I find a `source_S_` type artifact).

## The dependencies file

```
<info organisation="com.acme" module="pcp-parent" revision="${version.number}" status="${project.ivy.status}"/>

<configurations>
    <conf name="compileOnly"    visibility="public"                                 />
    <conf name="runtimeOnly"    visibility="public"                                 />
    <conf name="compile"        visibility="public" extends="compileOnly"           />
    <conf name="runtime"        visibility="public" extends="compile,runtimeOnly"   />
    <conf name="testCompile"    visibility="public" extends="compile"               />
    <conf name="testRuntime"    visibility="public" extends="runtime,testCompile"   />
    <conf name="test"           visibility="public" extends="testRuntime"           />
    <conf name="auth-iccrea"    visibility="public" extends="runtime"               />
    <conf name="auth-mps"       visibility="public" extends="runtime"               />
    <conf name="auth-db"        visibility="public" extends="runtime"               />
    <!-- Deprecated configuration ==> https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies -->
    <conf name="provided"       visibility="public" extends="compileOnly"           />
</configurations>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency org="org.springframework"                                     name="spring-core"                       rev="${spring.version}"      transitive="false"          conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework"                                     name="spring-aspects"                    rev="${spring.version}"      transitive="false"          conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework"                                     name="spring-aop"                        rev="${spring.version}"      transitive="false"          conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework"                                     name="spring-beans"                      rev="${spring.version}"      transitive="false"          conf="compile->default"/>

----------------

    <!-- jackson2 libs -->
    <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core"                              name="jackson-databind"                  rev="${jackson.version}"     transitive="false"          conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core"                              name="jackson-core"                      rev="${jackson.version}"     transitive="false"          conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core"                              name="jackson-annotations"               rev="${jackson.version}"     transitive="false"          conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat"                        name="jackson-dataformat-csv"            rev="${jackson.version}"     transitive="false"          conf="compile->default"/>


-------------

    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

And then `.ant/conf/ivy-settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<ivysettings>

    <settings defaultResolver="main" />
    <!--Authentication required for publishing (deployment). 'Artifactory Realm' is the realm used by Artifactory so don't change it. -->
    <credentials host="" realm="Artifactory Realm" username="deployment" passwd="" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="main" changingPattern=".*-BETA.*" checkmodified="true" changingMatcher="regexp">
            <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" root="https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/acme-all" />
            <url name="acme" m2compatible="false">
                <artifact pattern="https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/acme/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[module].[ext]" />
                <ivy pattern="https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/acme/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ivy.xml" />
            </url>
            <url name="acme-integration" m2compatible="false" changingPattern=".*-BETA.*" checkmodified="true" changingMatcher="regexp">
                <artifact pattern="https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/acme-integration/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[module](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]" />
                <ivy pattern="https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/acme-integration/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ivy-[revision].xml" />
            </url>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Maven Central is backed by Artifactory's cache, so this is why we have omitted it.

## Question

What is a correct Ant/Ivy retrieve configuration to get both jar and source?

If one here thinks there is a lot of confusion in my mind about Ant & Ivy, **they are correct**!!!!

Comment: Could you add your ivysettings.xml and ivy.xml? Or least just the parts relevant to the question

Comment: @cantSleepNow Question updated

Comment: One thing you may notice is the **abuse** of non-transitive dependency. This is by company order, and can't be changed at any cost

Comment: ok so I tried now with eclise, added just one dependency ```<dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name="jackson-databind" rev="2.11.2"/>``` and eclipse figured out the sources immediately, no special settings or patterns. I'll try next (can't promise when) withe intellij and then with your xmls

Comment: and same dependency with intellij idea + ivydea works. So sources are downloaded and "linked" correctly in the IDE. Again default settings everywhere...

Comment: The configs are not exactly standard thing and anyone publishing anything can define them at will, so when you look at the cache and how ivy.xml looks like for jackson databing, you see that it has ```<conf name="sources"``` which you don't have anywhere, so maybe that's the reason why you don't have the sources jar. so maybe start without ```config```s -- don't declare them at all in ivy.xml and don't use them in dependencies, and see if you get them. if you do, then it will be about tuning your configs.